# SUM two user roles in the same COLUMN

Tags: mysql

How do I SUM all users, I have two different users. One is student and the second is instructor.

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(user_role) FROM tbl_users WHERE user_role = 'student') as student, 
(SELECT COUNT(user_role) FROM tbl_users WHERE user_role = 'instructor') as instructor,
(SELECT SUM(user_role) FROM tbl_users) as totaluser
```

and why it doesn't add result as 1
in totaluser? It's 1 + 0 = 1. There should be at least 1 total user(s).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need

```
select student, instructor, student+instructor totaluser FROM ( 
select 
sum( if( user_role = 'student', 1, 0 ) ) AS student, 
sum( if( user_role = 'instructor', 1, 0 ) ) AS instructor  
from tbl_users ) t_alias
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options ;
1 - you can use "union all" for sum of the different selects

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY name

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' name, COUNT(name)
FROM table
```

or
2-

```
SELECT 
(select count(*) from table1 where selectedID = '123')
+
(select count(*) from table2 where selectedID = '123')
+
(select count(*) from table3 where selectedID = '123')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student, instructor, (SUM(student)+SUM(instructor)) AS totaluser
FROM tbl_users
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in this way:
'''select student,instructor,(student+instructor) as sum from(SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(user_role) FROM tbl_users WHERE user_role = 'student') as student,
(SELECT COUNT(user_role) FROM tbl_users WHERE user_role = 'instructor') ) table'''